# Explicit calculation of Laurent series coefficients by evaluating integral

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, cauchy-integral-formula

I want the Laurent expansion 
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n (z-a)^n
\end{equation}

of $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z+1)(z+3)}$ around the isolated pole $a =-1$ (for $|z+1|<2$). From a simple rewriting of the Taylor series, or from using Cauchy integral formula of order $n+1$, I find the correct answer, which is $c_n = 2^{-2-n}(-1)^{n+1}$ for $n\geq -1$ and $0$ otherwise.
However, for fun I wanted to ``manually'' integrate the expression
\begin{equation}
c_n =\frac1{2\pi i} \oint \frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi+1)^{n+1}}d\xi
\label{eq:}
\end{equation}
Selecting the circle with center $\xi =1$ and radius $r<2$, parameterized as $\xi+1 = r e^{i\theta}$ I get
\begin{equation}
c_n =\frac{r^{-n-1}}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-i\theta(n+1)}}{re^{i\theta}+2}d\theta.
\end{equation}

However, according to Mathematica, with

```
FullSimplify[
 Integrate[Exp[-I x (n + 1)]/(r Exp[I x] + 2), {x, 0, 2 Pi}], 
 Assumptions ->  Element[n,Integers] && 0 < r < 2],
```

this integral is $0$. What is wrong?

Comment: The integral is not $0$ for $n=-1$.

Comment: Indeed. It should not be 0 for any $n\geq -1$. Maybe it is a bug in Mathematica.

Comment: It looks like your question should be on [Mathematica.se]. Does Mathematica give a correct result if you eliminate the $r$ (effectively, use $r = 1$), and/or if you use a specific $n$?

Comment: Perhaps. With $r=1$ it gives $2^{-1 - n} \mathrm{Beta}[-(1/2), -1 - n, 0] \sin[n \pi]$, and with specific $n$ values it gives the correct result! (I thought I tried the latter already, but maybe it is on a different Mathematica version).

Comment: Remove `FullSimplify`command and you will get the answer: 

$${{2}^{-n-1}}{{r}^{n+1}}Beta\left( \frac{-1}{2},-n-1,0 \right)\sin \left( \pi n \right)$$
Note that using `FullSimplify` will set  $\sin \left( \pi n \right)=0$

Comment: I think you are then missing an r in the denominator of the integrand, no? (I get a hypergeometric function when $r\neq 1$) Regardless, if we put $r=1$, isn't it still a problem for integer $n$ compared to the known result, see my original post?

Comment: Answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/177175/general-result-from-integrate-differs-from-result-with-special-values)